# Highlight Differences across Workbook Ranges VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've managed to compare 3 separate ranges on one workbook with 3 single ranges across 3 workbooks.  Right now it's written to just pop up with a message box either letting me know the data is the same or the data is different.  What I would like to do is for the macro to not only let me know there are differences, but to also highlight where the differences are to me.  I guess this could be done by just highlighting the cells on the first workbook that are different to the other three or I guess it could also be done by pasting the different values  on the sheets in question from COL N onward.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim varDataMatrix() As Variant
Dim varDataMatrix2() As Variant 
Dim varDataMatrix3() As Variant 
Dim lngArrayCount As Long
Dim lngArrayCount2 As Long
Dim lngArrayCount3 As Long
Dim rngMyCell As Range
Dim rngMyCell2 As Range
Dim rngMyCell3 As Range
Dim wbWorkbookOne As Workbook
Dim wbWorkbookTwo As Workbook
Dim wbWorkbookThree As Workbook
Dim wbWorkbookFour As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbWorkbookOne = Workbooks("PositionTest.xls") 
Set wbWorkbookTwo = Workbooks("ATest.xlsx") 
Set wbWorkbookThree = Workbooks("BTest.xlsx") 
Set wbWorkbookFour = Workbooks("CTest.xlsx") 

'First create an array of the values in the desired range of the first workbook.
For Each rngMyCell In wbWorkbookOne.Sheets("Positions").Range("B3:B6") 
    lngArrayCount = lngArrayCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve varDataMatrix(1 To lngArrayCount) 
    varDataMatrix(lngArrayCount) = rngMyCell
Next rngMyCell

lngArrayCount = 0 'Initialise variable

'Loop through Array elements
For Each rngMyCell In wbWorkbookTwo.Sheets("A").Range("B2:B5")
    lngArrayCount = lngArrayCount + 1
    If rngMyCell.Value <> varDataMatrix(lngArrayCount) Then
       GoTo QuitRoutinue
    End If
Next rngMyCell


For Each rngMyCell2 In wbWorkbookOne.Sheets("Positions").Range("F3:F6") 
    lngArrayCount2 = lngArrayCount2 + 1
    ReDim Preserve varDataMatrix2(1 To lngArrayCount2) 
    varDataMatrix2(lngArrayCount2) = rngMyCell2
Next rngMyCell2

lngArrayCount2 = 0 'Initialise variable


'Loop through Array elements
For Each rngMyCell2 In wbWorkbookThree.Sheets("B").Range("B2:B5") 
    lngArrayCount2 = lngArrayCount2 + 1
    If rngMyCell2.Value <> varDataMatrix2(lngArrayCount2) Then
       GoTo QuitRoutinue
    End If
Next rngMyCell2


For Each rngMyCell3 In wbWorkbookOne.Sheets("Positions").Range("J3:J6") 
    lngArrayCount3 = lngArrayCount3 + 1
    ReDim Preserve varDataMatrix3(1 To lngArrayCount3) 'Append the record to the existing array
    varDataMatrix3(lngArrayCount3) = rngMyCell3
Next rngMyCell3

lngArrayCount3 = 0 'Initialise variable



For Each rngMyCell3 In wbWorkbookFour.Sheets("C").Range("B2:B5") 'Workbook one range is A10:A15 on 'Sheet2'.
    lngArrayCount3 = lngArrayCount3 + 1
    If rngMyCell3.Value <> varDataMatrix3(lngArrayCount3) Then
       GoTo QuitRoutinue
    End If
Next rngMyCell3


'If we get here both datasets have matched.
Set wbWorkbookOne = Nothing
Set wbWorkbookTwo = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Erase varDataMatrix() 'Deletes the varible contents, free some memory
MsgBox "Data is the same.", vbInformation
Exit Sub



Set wbWorkbookOne = Nothing
Set wbWorkbookTwo = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Erase varDataMatrix() 'Deletes the varible contents, free some memory
MsgBox "Data is different.", vbExclamation
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights differences on Positions sheet and shows values in columns L to N. Uses Application.Transpose to create 1D arrays from a vertical range of cells. Note : Transpose won't work for a non-contiguous range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()

    Dim ws(3) As Worksheet, sht, w, n As Long
    sht = Array("Positions", "A", "B", "C")
    
    For Each w In Array("PositionTest.xls", "ATest.xlsx", "BTest.xlsx", "CTest.xlsx")
        Set ws(n) = Workbooks(w).Sheets(sht(n))
        n = n + 1
    Next
    
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, diff As Long
    Dim rng0 As Range, rngN As Range, a As Range, b As Range
    Dim ar0, arN
    ' compare sheets
    For n = 1 To 3
         Set rng0 = ws(0).Range("H5:H7,H9:H11,H13:H19,H21:H22").Offset(, (n - 1) * 4) ' H, L, P
         Set rngN = ws(n).Range("E3:E18") ' sheet A, B, C
         ' copy to array
         arN = Application.Transpose(rngN)
    
         i = 0
         For Each a In rng0
             i = i + 1
             r = a.Row
             
             ' cells on position sheet
             Set b = ws(0).Cells(r, "R").Offset(, n) ' diff in col L,M,N
             
             ' compare arrays
             If a.Value <> arN(i) Then
                 a.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' yellow
                 b.Value = rngN.Cells(i, 1)
                 diff = diff + 1
             Else
                 a.Interior.Pattern = False
                 b.Clear
             End If
         Next
    Next
   
    MsgBox diff & " differences", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep this was perfect thank you!  First ever time using VBA for myself and you did what I wanted with significantly less code as well!

Comment: Hi CDP, I have been trying to replicate the above code but with the full amount of data/ranges etc.  Unfortunately I'm running into an Error with the first range (rng0) as it has to skip some cells therefore the actual range is "H5:H7,H9:H11,H13:H19,H21:H22".  This is leading to a mismatch error in "For i = 1 To UBound(ar0)".  Dont suppose you have a fix for this?

Comment: @lukeajn if that replaces "B3:B6" what replaces "B2:B5"

Comment: Hey, so that would be E3:E18!

Comment: @LukeAJN rng0 is 15 cells but E3:E18 is 16 ?

Comment: Whoops meant E3:E17, my bad

Comment: @lukeajn OK try updated code. You can amend rngN is wont make any difference

Comment: Yep perfect that got it again thank you so much!

Comment: @lukeajn I suggest you delete your latest question